# How to change the locale code for a theme in magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, language

I have a theme that will output all the static file to

`pub\static\frontend\VendorName\thmemeName\fr_FR`, but now i want to change it to `pub\static\frontend\VendorName\thmemeName\en_US,` What are the things i have to set ?

Comment: Change locale to us English. This will automatically cahnge the code and also the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Locale from `Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> General >> Locale Option >> Locale >> English` //Here you have to select only one English locale

Static files are generate based on above locale setting, if multiple locale set then it will generate multiple static files as per locale

Set above configuration and run below command, It will generate only `pub\static\frontend\VendorName\thmemeName\en_US`

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change locale for store view from Stores > Configuration. As per below screenshot.

[image]

And then deploy static content using below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```